# How to show that measurable functions preserve mean independence?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables such that 
$$\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y=y)=\mathbb{E}(X) $$
 for all $y\in \operatorname{Supp}(Y)$. How can I show that for any measurable function $f$ we have  $$\mathbb{E}(X\mid f(Y)=f_y)=\mathbb{E}(X)$$ for all $f_y\in \operatorname{Supp}(f(Y))$? Seems very intuitive but I havent been able to come up with a formal proof.

Comment: How do you define $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y=y)$ when $Y$ is continuous?

Comment: I define it as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X|Y}(x|y) dx$. Maybe I should have added that joint and conditional distributions of $X$ and $Y$ exist etc.

Comment: Conditional densities are not needed to define conditional expectations. Please write down every needed hypothesis (once again, if $Y$ is continuous, you need to define  $\mathbb{E}(X\mid f(Y)=f_y)$ carefully before the question makes sense).

Comment: tell me what makes no sense and I'll be happy to clarify. Conditional expectations are defined as in Ross's "A First Course in Probability"
http://ins.sjtu.edu.cn/people/lqyan/Teaching/TeachingPDF/Ross_8th_ed_English.pdf

Comment: Conditional densities $\ne$ conditional expectations. As long as you avoid the question, we cannot go far.

Comment: I never said conditional density = conditional expectations. I said
$E(X∣Y=y) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X|Y}(x|y) dx$

Comment: OK. You try to avoid explaining what you know and how you define the notation $E(X\mid f(Y)=z)$. Too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think the general result is completely obvious, but here's at least a result for the case where $f$ is injective. I'll assume that the variables $X$ and $Y$ take their values in the real numbers. Let $(\nu_y)_{y\in\mathbb{R}}$ be the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$. Formally, this means that
$$
  P(X\in A,Y\in B) = \int 1_B(y) \nu_y(A) dY(P)(y)
$$
for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$. It then also holds that
$$
  E(X | Y = y) = \int w d\nu_y(w).
$$
The above might in fact conveniently be taken as the definition of conditional expectations. Now let $(\mu_z)_{z\in \mathbb{R}}$ be the conditional distribution of $X$ given $f(Y)$. This means that
$$
  P(X\in A,f(Y)\in f(B)) = \int 1_B(z) \mu_z(A) df(Y)(P)(z),
$$
and
$$
  E(X | f(Y) = z) = \int w d\mu_z(w).
$$
Now note that
$$
  P(X\in A, f(Y) \in B)
  =P(X\in A, Y\in f^{-1}(B))\\
  =\int 1_{f^{-1}(B)}(y) \nu_y(A) dY(P)(y)
  =\int 1_{B}(f(y)) \nu_{f^{-1}(f(y))}(A) dY(P)(y) \\
  =\int 1_{B}(y) \nu_{f^{-1}(y)}(A) df(Y)(P)(y).
$$
By uniqueness of conditional distributions, $\mu_z = \nu_{f^{-1}(z)}$. This essentially states that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $f(Y) = z$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y = f^{-1}(z)$. It then follows that
$$
  E(X | f(Y) = f(y)) = E(X | Y = y).
$$
In particular, the result for the case where the conditional expectation is constant follows from this. However, the above arguments are only valid for when $f$ is injective...

Answer (score 1):

The conditional expectation $\mathbb E(X\mid Y=y)$ in general depends on $y$, so call it $g(y)$.  Then the expression $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)$ denotes the random variable $g(Y)$.  So $g(Y)$ is a constant random variable, equal to one particular number with probability $1$.  Therefore for any measurable set $A$, we have $\mathbb E(X\mid Y\in A)$ is that same number.  Now let $A=\{w : f(y)=w\}$.

Maybe I'll add a more measure-theoretic point of view later.

Comment: Would it be wrong to say that $E[X | Y = y]$ as a regular conditional probability is equivalent to $E[X | \sigma(Y)] = E[X]$? In this case, $\sigma(f(Y)) \subset \sigma(Y)$, hence $E[X | \sigma(f(Y))] = E[X]$.

Comment: @snarski : $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)$ is the same as $\mathbb E(X\mid\sigma(Y))$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry, I meant: don't we have $E[X | Y = y] = E[X]$ for all $y$ on the support of $Y$ if and only if $E[X | \sigma(Y)] = E[X]$? It certainly seems to be the case when $Y$ is a simple function.